# Bash - Proxy server using socat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to make an http proxy using socat, But I don't know why the request stop suddenly, and there isn't any content in the webpage.
it's just transfer the HTTP request from bowser to the web server. then back with the response.

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:666,fork EXEC:"./httproxy.sh"
```

Redirect port 80 to 666

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 666
```

httproxy.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function main() {
    REQUEST_HEADERS=()

    read -r line 
    line=${line%%$'\r'}
    read -r REQUEST <<< "${line}"
    
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        line=${line%%$'\r'}
        [ -z "${line}" ] && break
        REQUEST_HEADERS+=( "${line}" )
    done
    
    printf "${REQUEST}\r\n" &> request.log
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#REQUEST_HEADERS[@]}; i++)); do
        [[ "${REQUEST_HEADERS[$i]}" =~ ^Host:[[:space:]](.*) ]] && IP=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        printf "${REQUEST_HEADERS[$i]}\r\n" &>> request.log
    done
    printf "$(cat request.log)\r\n\r\n\r\n" | nc ${IP} 80
}

main
```

Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK....
{HTTP Content}

Immediately after the content:
HTTP/1.1 405....
```

I've tested it with a lots of 'Http' web pages sometimes the html content arrived
.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT print variables by putting them in `printf` format string.

Instead of

```
printf "$var\r\n"
```

do

```
printf '%s\r\n' "$var"
```

As a rule of thumb, enclose the format string with single quotes, which will prevent any inadvertent variable or process substitution.

Of course, the same goes for your `printf "$(cat request.log)\r\n\r\n\r\n"`

Why?

- If `var` starts with `-` (minux sign), printf will understand your format string as an option. This will never happen with an HTTP GET request.
- If `var` contains a `%` character, *which is very common in HTTP requests*, printf will interpret it as a format directive.

Besides, you probably add too many empty lines `\r\n` after the request. One seems enough since you append `request.log` with lines that already end with `\r\n`:

```
{ cat request.log; printf '\r\n'; } | nc ...
```

(it's possible you don't even have to add any empty line since the request should already end with one)

Comment: Thank you, it's working better than before , But :) the web page still without any content 

https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-b4c0b2b5ea87.gif

Comment: It might be another issue. Your code is unnecessarily complicated because you are capturing each line, removing CR, then readding CR. Storing the initial request to request.log is one line. Retrieving the original Host line is one simpe sed/awk command. Sending request.log to the Host is a third line. No need to modify any end of line. Begin with a code that doesn't modify the request. Then modify it if you really need to.